# ExtJS 6.5 Ext.Form.field.Date with InputMask

Tags: javascript, extjs, datetimepicker, extjs5

When I apply a **[InputMask](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.form.field.Date.html#cfg-inputMask)** to a **[datefield](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.form.field.Date.html)** and try input by keyboard the date, it returns an error, have tried it at fiddle and the error also occurs, anyone have any workaround or idea about these?

the code is really simple:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        requires: [' Ext.field.InputMask '],
        width: 300,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        title: 'Dates',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'datefield',
            anchor: '100%',
            fieldLabel: 'Date',
            name: 'date',
            format: 'd/m/Y',
            inputMask: '99/99/9999'
        }]
    });
```

error at console: [errorimage.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcfAg.png)

fiddle sencha: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/32lf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Keller InputMask was introduced in Ext 6.5.0 and are well tested only in modern toolkit. But you can use it in classic.

The mixin is inside the core package but Sencha guarantee better working only in modern toolkit.

InputMask Mixin is compatible only with textfield

read this guide please.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/guides/whats_new/whats_new.html#whats_new-_-whats_new_-_input_masking

I hope it helps.